# Dealing with empty tags in pear xml_serializer

Tags: php, xml, pear

Im using PEAR XML Serializer to generate xml results from array inputs. I found out that empty array elements are encoded like this: <arraykey/>. I'd rather prefer it this way <arraykey></arraykey>

Below are my options:

```
            $options = array
            (
                'indent' => '   ',
                'defaultTagName' => $this->xml_tag_name,
                'addDecl' => true,
                'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                'rootName' => $this->xml_root_name,
                XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => true
            );
```

Are there any other options to add to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the actual state of the library no, it uses [PEAR XML_Util](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Util) and if you look at the code of `XML_Util::createTagFromArray()`, it does the following for empty tags:

```
if (!isset($tag['content']) || (string)$tag['content'] == '')
{
    $tag = sprintf('<%s%s />', $tag['qname'], $attList);
}
```

You could probably fake empty content with a string that contains a space such as `' '` but that would result into something like `<arraykey> </arraykey>`.

BTW, `<arraykey/>` is totally legal in XML (it's recommended for empty tags, it's also used in XHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a concrete reason you prefer the `<tag></tag>` format over `<tag />`? Noting that (as another poster said) `<tag />` is totally valid XML. Personally I prefer self-closing for an empty tag.